# Exporting data into excel properly

Tags: python, export-to-excel

I am trying to export data into an excel file and I cannot seem to get the text properly in one cell but instead I get each character of the word in a different cell. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance

the code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import csv

page= requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')

tree= html.fromstring(page.content)

buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')

prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')

print ('Buyers ', buyers)
print('  ')
print ('Prices ', prices)

b = open('Exapmle1.csv','w')
a=csv.writer(b)

row = 0
col = 0

for item in (buyers):
    a.writerows(item)
    row += 1
b.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text ([str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) type) is a sequence of single characters therefore your iterator is not going to return words.

If you want to get every word (a substring separated by white spaces) you can do something like this

`for item in buyers.split():
   print(item)
   # rest of your code`

Note that the [writerows()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) method that you're using treats its parameter as a sequence as well, so if you pass a string it will write each character separately. You need to make sure your string itself is an element of a squence:

`for item in buyers.split():
   print(item)
   a.writerows([item])`

Or possibly a slightly more concise version:

`a.writerows([[item] for item in buyers.split()])`

Comment: that fixed the problem in python but not in excel